# is it possible to register event handler like this?

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't it work?

```
<body>
    <p id="element_id">
        blah
    </p>


</body>




var pcontent = document.getElementById('element_id').innerHTML;

function exit(){

document.getElementById('id2').innerHTML = pcontent;

}

var a = '<div id="id2"><input type="button" value="exit" onclick= "exit()"></div>' ;


document.getElementById('element_id').innerHTML= a;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B94kx/

Comment: What are you trying? Can you explain bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not your code but instead the way in which you are running the code on jsfiddle.  Your fiddle has the `onLoad` option set which means all of the javascript code runs in the `onLoad` callback.  So the `exit` function is defined in the callback and not in the global scope.  Hence the event handler can't reference `exit`.

This can be fixed by simply removing the `onLoad` option and instead using `no wrap (body)`

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NjbVh/

Or alternately you can force `exit` to be a global by attaching it to the `window`.

```
window.exit = function() {
  document.getElementById('id2').innerHTML = pcontent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the function `exit` is not a global function. `onclick="exit()"` tries to run a global function called `exit`, which doesn't exist.  You defined the function in the scope of the event handler (it's the window's `onLoad` event, as you can see from the panel on the left).

The simple solution is to define the function as a global value by setting it as a property of the window object:

```
window.exit = function() {
    document.getElementById('id2').innerHTML = pcontent;
};
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B94kx/1/)

---

A nicer solution would be to stop misusing the DOM by using `innerHTML` and inline event handlers. It's a bit clunky, but [here's your code using proper DOM methods](http://jsfiddle.net/B94kx/25/).

Answer (score 0):

You are losing your scope, making exit() not visible
here's a quick and dirty solution:

```
var pcontent = document.getElementById('element_id').innerHTML;

window.exit = function() {
     document.getElementById('id2').innerHTML = pcontent;
}

var a = '<div id="id2"><input type="button" value="exit" onclick="window.exit()"></div>' ;

document.getElementById('element_id').innerHTML= a;
```